# Will there be an Enterprise bot Template in Bot Builder SDK v4?

Tags: c#, templates, botframework

I have seen various developments to V4 SDK. The latest V4 SDK has Echo bot , Core bot and Empty bot templates. Will there be a GA version for enterprise template in V4 anytime soon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a better / larger template called "Virtual Assistant". It is available.

A few useful links:

- Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-virtual-assistant-introduction?view=azure-bot-service-4.0
- Main repo: https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/blob/master/docs/tutorials/csharp/virtualassistant.md
- Template for VS2017 and VS2019: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BotBuilder.VirtualAssistantTemplate